# Variable in bound for #points in a elliptic curve over a finite field is a trace?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I already know that the number of points $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ in an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $q+1-t$, $|t| \le 2 \sqrt{q}$.

The thing is, the article 'Nonsingular Plane Cubic Curves over Finite Fields' by Schoof mentions that this $t$ is exactly the trace of the Frobenius endomorphism over $E$.
[image]

I couldn't find a reference for that claim. Does anybody have a proof or a link to it?

Comment: What about reference number [17]?

Comment: It's Tate's 'The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves'. It just mentions the theorem and says Hasse proved it around the 1930's.

Comment: I would assume most textbooks on elliptic curves prove this. For instance, Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Ch. V, Theorem 2.3.1.

Comment: There are even online references: [here](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2019/LectureNotes8.pdf) are some notes from MIT.

Comment: Thanks, André 3000, your reference really helped me out.